# Выбрать сразу несколько записей из select

Tags: php, html, mysql, select

Добрый день! Нужно выбрать сразу несколько записей из select, и отправить запрос.

Нужно как изменить этот код запроса, чтобы была возможность выбрать 2 значения.

```
<li>
<label>Тип товара</label>
<select name="form_type" id="type" size="1" >

<option value="mobile" >Мобильные телефоны</option>
<option value="notebook" >Ноутбуки</option>
<option value="notepad" >Планшеты</option>

</select>
</li>

<li>
<label>Категория</label>
<select name="form_category" size="10" >

<?php
$category = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM category",$link);

If (mysql_num_rows($category) > 0)
{
$result_category = mysql_fetch_array($category);
do
{

  echo '

  <option value="'.$result_category["id"].'" >'.$result_category["brand"].'</option>

  ';

}
 while ($result_category = mysql_fetch_array($category));
}
?>

</select>
</ul>
```

Хочу из Select-а в Админке выбирать сразу 2 категорию

[image: Хочу из этого Select-а выбирать сразу 2 категории]

Comment: <select multiple>...</select>
Вы об этом или об запросе к БД?

Comment: Запрос к Базе Данных

Comment: Лично я не очень понял, чего вы хотите добиться. Чтобы у вас вывод сразу какой-то был? Ил что именно?

Comment: Если запрос к несколькім наблицам то както так:
"SELECT category*, some.* FROM category, some"

Comment: Хочу из Select-а в Админке выбирать сразу 2 категорию, и в сайте товар был добавлен на обе категорию

Comment: Вопрос непонятен? Из столбца Brand нужно выбрать два значения! Сюда $category = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM category",$link); можно как нибудь запихнуть код который можно будет выбирать две значения?

Comment: "SELECT brand FROM category LIMIT 2;" - так? )

Comment: Нет не так. Так сделан вывод две значения на select в админку, у меня в коде уже выполнен вывод все значения, а теперь хочу выбрать из этого select-а в админке, две значения и добавить на сайт. А сейчас я могу выбирать только одно значение.

Answer (score 0):

1. Никогда, слышите, никогда, не мешайте верстку вперемешку с запросами к БД, это тормозит загрузку страницы, потому что показалась шапка сайта, потом пошел запрос к базе, сервер подумал, выплюнул результат, отдал еще часть верстки, а потом споткнулся, и у Вас ошибка на странице, а ниже ее пустота. Сначала делайте все запросы к БД, пишите всю логику страницы, а уже потом выводите теги с условиями на php.
2. Касаясь Вашего вопроса, сначала нужно получить все категории нужные, а уже в select гонять полученный массив через foreach (if-do-while, как и mysql-функции вообще забудьте как страшный сон, на дворе 21 век).
3. В админке лучше использовать checkbox'ы вместо select'а, так Вы избежите ситуации, когда я случайно нажму не туда без Ctrl и уберу все выделенные значения.

1.1. Получаем данные до вывода html:

```
$allCategories=array();
$categories=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM category",$link);
while($category=mysql_fetch_array($categories)){
  $allCategories[$category->id]=$category;
  unset($category);
}
```

1.2. Выводим полученные категории в нужном месте:

```
if(!empty($allCategories)){
  foreach($allCategories as $category){
?>
<option value="<?=$category["id"]?>"><?=$category["brand"]?></option>
<?php
  unset($category);
  }
}
```